# jquery live click event not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm using the following code, and it works fine in all browsers I've seen, IE9 is fine but then I come to IE8 and it doesn't work at all.. just for reference the `#cal_popup_table` element is dynamically added to the page..

```
        $("#cal_popup_table tbody tr td a").live('click', function() {
            $('.datepick-cmd-today').text(from_month + ' ' + from_year);

            var test = from_yeartest + '-' + from_monthtest + '-' + from_daytest;
            var test_new = test.split("-");
            var today = test_new[0] + '-' + test_new[1] + '-' + test_new[2];

            $("#arrival").val(today);
        });
```

Could anyone shed some light on why it might not be working properly, the code inside the function doesn't matter as a simple `alert()` doesn't work either.. the click event just never fires at all

UPDATE - this is the code (trimmed out some content etc) that is inserted into the page

```
<div id="cal_popup" class="datepick-popup" style="position: absolute; left: 901px; top: 219px; ">
<div class="datepick" style="width: 195px; ">
    <div class="datepick-nav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Show the previous month" class="datepick-cmd datepick-cmd-prev  datepick-disabled">&lt;</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Show today's month" class="datepick-cmd datepick-cmd-today ">December 2012</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Show the next month" class="datepick-cmd datepick-cmd-next ">&gt;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="datepick-month-row">
        <div class="datepick-month">
            <table id="cal_popup_table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepicker_link dp1354708800000   datepick-today datepick-highlight" title="Select Wednesday, Dec 5, 2012">5</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try by removing the `tbody`:

```
$("#cal_popup_table tr td a").live('click', function() {
```

Some browsers add `<tbody>` to automatically-generated tables, but IE 8 does not.

That's why JS failed to execute your code in IE 8.

Comment: thanks for the help but this doesn't seem have to changed anything still works in everything but IE8

Answer (score 0):

Use on()

```
    $("#cal_popup_table").on('click', 'tr td a', function() {
        alert('a');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just `checked your code in ie8` and `its working absolutely fine no problems whatsoever`, i have done something in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J8ysn/1/

> **This is the jQuery code i have tried.**

```
    $('<table border="1"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>')
        .appendTo('body')
        .attr({"id":"cal_popup_table"});

    $('<a href="#">clik</a>').appendTo("#cal_popup_table tbody tr td");


    $("#cal_popup_table tbody tr td a").live('click', function() {
          alert('live clicked');
    });
```

Comment: i can't understand why mine isn't working then.. must be something along the line